# How to change license file permanently using lmutil (FlexLM) on Windows

Tags: windows, license

I can change the license file using GUI utility LMTools on Windows and the change becomes permanent after that.
How can I achieve the same using the commandline utility lmutil? I want to be able to permanently change the license file using a batch script.
I tried this sequence, but it does not work as expected.

lmutil lmdown -c current_license_file -vendor vendor -force

lmutil lmpath -override vendor license_file

lmutil lmreread -c new_license_file -vendor vendor -all

All these commands go through fine without errors. But after this when I open lmtools and check if the license file has changed, it still points to the old file.

Please help.